# How to print the command line itself in log file for log tracking purpose?

Tags: batch-file

I have a java code that is called through .bat file. The batch works fine. Is there a way I could print this command line which I'm executing to the stdout (log) file ?

For example, my command is

```
call dpp.bat -r %BASE_URL% views -af xyz.csv >> creation.log 2>&1
```

In my bat file I have multiple commands of various types of such kind. While executing this single batch file, everything gets executed one by one and all logs are written to that single file creation.log. And user gets lost seeing the log, which command line executed what !

Is there a simple way like adding some line that would print the command line too to the log file ?

Comment: Why are you using `Call`? What happens if you remove it? What happens if you do not include `@Echo Off`?

Comment: Because call, executes another batch 'dpp' (in this case)

Comment: It would have been easier to have used `dpp.cmd` or `dpp.bat` then, because you absolutely didn't tell us that. I have removed the irrelevant tags from your question, _(based upon the information you have provided)_, and modified your code to make it clearer that you're `call`ing a `.bat` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was very simple, just put `echo %*` This would print the arguments passed in command line.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to write both the command echoes and the command outputs to the log file.

To achieve this you could do the following:

- Place the code you want to log into a sub-routine that is then called by [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html).
- [Redirect](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) only the output of the `call` command to the log file.
- Place `@echo off` into the main section of the batch file.
- Place `@echo on` into the sub-routine.
- Do not forget to place [`exit /B`](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) at the end of the main section.

Here is an example:

```cmd
@rem // Turn command echoes off in the main section:
@echo off
@rem // Redirect only the output of `call` to the log file:
call :SUB >> "creation.log" 2>&1
@rem // Terminate main section:
@exit /B

:SUB
    @rem // Turn command echoes on in the sub-section:
    @echo on
    @rem /* Place all command lines you want to log here;
    @rem    ensure NOT to precede these lines with `@`: */
    call dpp -r %BASE_URL% views -af xyz.csv
    @rem // Terminate sub-section:
    @exit /B
```

---

Alternatively, you could place each command into a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) that iterates only once:

```cmd
@rem // Turn command echoes on:
@echo on
@rem // Place all command lines you want to log into `for` loops that iterate once:
@(for %%# in (.) do call dpp -r %BASE_URL% views -af xyz.csv) > "creation.log" 2>&1
@rem // Terminate script:
@exit /B
```